# How to select dynamic date from date picker

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, daterangepicker

I want to make a automated program which can click on the date of 7 days, before the current date from date-range picker using Selenium Webdriver in Python??
Here is a code of date picker

```html
<tr>
<td class="available off" data-title="r0c0">30</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r0c1">1</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r0c2">2</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r0c3">3</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r0c4">4</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r0c5">5</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r0c6">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="available" data-title="r1c0">7</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r1c1">8</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r1c2">9</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r1c3">10</td>
<td class="available" data-title="r1c4">11</td>
<td class="available active start-date" data-title="r1c5">12</td>
<td class="available in-range" data-title="r1c6">13</td></tr>
```

This is the html code of only 2 rows in which second last row represent the current data. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0fyW.png)I am attaching the snip of how my date range picker looks

The piece of code which I have tried is

```
cal_left = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.daterangepicker.dropdown-menu.show-calendar.opensright > div.calendar.left')
cal_left.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'12')]").click()
```

Here the first line of code is to select left calendar as there are two and second line is to select a particular date and click on it, it is not giving eany kind of Exception or error but also not clicking on the date.

Comment: @Tuks I have edited it now

Comment: @Tuks it is running but not working on that date-range-picker. Means that particular date(here which is 12) is not getting clicked.

Comment: @Tuks I am really sorry but due to privacy concern thats not possible for me but I can make u available more html code

Comment: @Tuks can you please tell me how to make a xpath of this element in the terms of text                                                                                             <td class="available" data-title="r1c0">7</td>                                                  like 7 here.. Please I need it

Comment: `.//tr/td[@class='available'][text()='7']`

Comment: @Tuks Terminal is showing it invalid syntax after applying it on driver object.

Comment: @Tuks thanks your last code which you have sent helped me a lot, due to silly mistake I git error.

Comment: @Tuks Again its showing problem, now I want to give the date by a variable like instead of '7', I want to give (todays's date - 7) but, program is considering that variable as a text and showing the error "unable to locate it".What should I do now??